# The most efficient method using the Big O notation to avoid multiple forEach loops

Tags: swift, algorithm, foreach, big-o

I have created these two objects :

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let genderId: Int

}

struct Gender {
    let id: Int
    let sex: String
}
```

and create these arrays :

```
let persons = [
    Person(name: "Steve", genderId: 1),
    Person(name: "Kate", genderId: 2),
    Person(name: "Mark", genderId: 1),
    Person(name: "Pam", genderId: 2)

]

let genders = [
    Gender(id: 1, sex: "girl"),
    Gender(id: 2, sex: "boy"),
]
```

What should be the most efficient algorithm using the big O notation in order to create an object array based on this new object :

```
struct PersonWithGenderString {
    let name: String
    let genderString: String
}
```

I already wrote this method using two forEach loops but I am looking for way which iterate the less time possible :

```
persons.forEach { (person) in
    genders.forEach { (gender) in
        if person.genderId == gender.id {
            let personWithGenderString = PersonWithGenderString(name: person.name, genderString: gender.sex)
            print(personWithGenderString)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: the most efficient algorithm actually needs an efficient data structure. Ie one that has O(1) lookup for a gender of given id. Eg a hash table

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61527981/3141234

Answer (score -1):

If you store the `Gender` objects in order by `Gender.id` in the `genders` array, which it appears you do, you can access them directly, instead of using the inner loop:

```
persons.forEach { (person) in
    let genderIndex = person.genderId - 1
    if genderIndex < 0 || genderIndex > genders.size {
       // handle this error (array out of bounds)
    }
    let personWithGenderString = PersonWithGenderString(name: person.name, genderString: genders[genderIndex].sex)
    print(personWithGenderString)
}
```

This would be O(1) to convert any particular `Person` to `PersonWithGenderString` and O(n) to convert n `Person`s to n `PersonWithGenderString`s

Comment: `genderIndex < 0 || genderIndex > genders.size` don't write that. It's super error prone. Just use `genders.indices.contains(genderIndex)`. Didn't down vote, btw.